# Sudden shutdown when running new hardware

Tags: 18.04, 20.04

I got a realtively new laptop, `HP Elitebook 840 g6`. 16GB RAM, 500GB SSD storage, core i7 8th Gen. I tried running both `ubuntu 18.04` and `20.04`. With 18.04, there was a problem with audio (microphone) not working, I found a solution online and got it working though with very low volume output.

On both versions, the laptop suddenly shuts down without warning, and this means i loose all unsaved work. I have tried looking everywhere for the past 2 weeks and I can't seem to find a solution.

The laptop works perfectly fine on windows OS and doesnt shut down. (I really hate working on windows though). Is this a hardware problem or ubuntu problem? How can I fix this? I ran a hardware probe and these were the results https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=95f53c1b72

**UPDATE**

An observation: just before it goes off, I noticed the fan tries to turn on, and then immediately the laptop turns off. On Windows OS, the fan turns on successfully and the laptop does not shut off

Comment: Look in the log files for any hints on what makes the system shutdown: /var/log/syslog is a good place to start.

Comment: everything looks normal there

Comment: Have you updated UEFI and updated SSD firmware?

Comment: After a "sudden shutdown", the terminal command `sudo journalctl -b -1 -e` will show you the end of the log for the previous boot. If there's no hint, suspect overheating or power problems.

Comment: I have run the command too and no hint at all, just NetworkManager logs.